# How to find all possible combinations from a list with only two elements and no duplicates with Python?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have the following:

```
list = ["player1", "player2", "player3"]
```

I want to find all possible combinations of two elements of that list, but with no duplicates. I have tried to work with the itertools.combinations() but without the desired result.

I'm looking for a result like this:

```
player1, player2
player1, player3
player2, player3
```

Can someone help me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `list(itertools.combinations(lst, 2))`? Don't call your list `list` because it overwrites a builtin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, as it makes use of `combinations` so import it from `itertools` like this:

```
from itertools import combinations

#also it's good practice not to use list, so for sake of it call it something else
listPlayers = ["player1", "player2", "player3"] 

getPairPlayers = sorted(map(sorted, combinations(set(listPlayers), 2)))

print(getPairPlayers)
```

Output:

```
[['player1', 'player2'], ['player1', 'player3'], ['player2', 'player3']]
```